# Possible to rename sub domain for gitolite host?

Tags: linux, git, gitolite

When I setup my gitolite server back in the day, I called it `gitolite.example.com` and the users are asking for it to be `git.example.com` instead.

**Question**

If I change the sub domain will all the users repos continue to work?

Or do I have to change something in each of the users repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the URL of the repositories you will either have to update the URL in every checked out repo on every client, or create a redirect on `gitolite.example.com` to redirect requests to `git.example.com`. This way already checked out repos will continue to work, while newly checked out repos will directly get the new URL.

To change the URL in a checked out repository you can [use this command](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/):

```
git remote set-url origin https://git.example.com/PATH/TO/REPOSITORY.git
```

The redirect obviously depends on the webserver you are using.